# Loading Gif Page Does not load background images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loader

I have a gif that appears as my site is loading however the gif dissapers and the page appears after everything has loaded except the background images called via css.

How could I have the gif fade away only after the background images have loaded.

I am using this code for the loader:

html:

```
<html class="loading">
    <!-- All the things -->
</html>
```

css:

```
html {
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}
html, body {
    /* For the loading indicator to be vertically centered ensure */
    /* the html and body elements take up the full viewport */
    min-height: 100%;
}
html.loading {
    /* Replace #333 with the background-color of your choice */
    /* Replace loading.gif with the loading image of your choice */
    background: #333 url('loading.gif') no-repeat 50% 50%;

    /* Ensures that the transition only runs in one direction */
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0;
    transition: background-color 0;
}
body {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}
html.loading body {
    /* Make the contents of the body opaque during loading */
    opacity: 0;

    /* Ensures that the transition only runs in one direction */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0;
    transition: opacity 0;
}
```

javascript

```
// IE10+
document.getElementsByTagName( "html" )[0].classList.remove( "loading" );

// All browsers
document.getElementsByTagName( "html" )[0].className.replace( /loading/, "" );

// Or with jQuery
$( "html" ).removeClass( "loading" );
```

Thank you

Comment: where do you define the background in the css?

Comment: like this:`#homepage {
background: url(/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/home.jpg) fixed;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
background-size:cover;
background-position: bottom; 
overflow: auto; 
margin: 0 auto; 
width: 100%; 
position: relative;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
height: 100vh;
}`

Comment: what does your console say? is there any error shown? it might be just the wrong path.

Comment: and is there a working example or a live view of the page?

Comment: One way is to use `window.onload` or jquery's `$(window).load` which will fire when everything on the pages has finished loading.

Comment: http://interzonestudio.com

Comment: window.onload worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Works perfectly for me in firefox. In Chrome and Safari the gif does not move however the scroll bar appears and can scroll the height of the page. Only when scrolling does the gif move. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.splash').fadeTo(555,0, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="splash" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image:url(mygif); background-repeat: repeat;">&nbsp;</div>
    <!-- All the things -->
</body>
</html>
```

tested ! => http://jsfiddle.net/3m3S8/

Comment: `$(document).ready` is fired when the dom is loaded, not the page with all images.

Comment: Thanks but this does not acomplish what I want.The gif is visible while most of the page is loaded but the page still loads without the background.

Comment: This was mainly to show the principle of fading and removing elements. You could apply the same priciples by binding the load of the images you want to wait for